# Spelling "autocorrect" in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have read the old posts about disabling autocorrection in Gmail. Some people indicate is not a feature of Gmail what bears the autocorrect feature but of the browser. Regardless of what I do in my browser settings as well as Gmail's, still the auotocrrect feature prevails.

However, when I use my yahoo mail autocorection does not happen. I am not an expert handling applications, but this tells me that it is a Gmail feature, and not of my browser's.

Are there any new thoughts about this? Anybody has found a way to disable this feature in Gmail? It is really annoying. Several times I have to email again the people I have sent emails to apologizing for a mistake that Gmail made when "correcting" my text.

Comment: Which browser(s) and OS are you using? Gmail itself does not have an "autocorrect" feature that I'm aware of?

Comment: What language(s) are you using? Which Gmail "input tools" do you have enabled? Can you provide a screenshot (or link to one) please?